# No change in key value MUL in mySQL table after drop foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

```
student table:
+---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| stu_id        | int      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| stu_name      | char(30) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |       |
| stu_branch_id | int      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+

branch table:
+--------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| branch_id          | int      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| branch_name        | char(30) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |       |
| branch_building_no | int      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> alter table student add constraint fk_student foreign key (stu_branch_id) references branch(branch_id);
Query OK, 5 rows affected (2.69 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

desc student;
+---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| stu_id        | int      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| stu_name      | char(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| stu_branch_id | int      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> alter table student 
    -> drop foreign key fk_student;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.21 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> desc student;
+---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| stu_id        | int      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| stu_name      | char(30) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |       |
| stu_branch_id | int      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)



mysql> alter table student 
    -> add constraint fk_student foreign key (stu_id_branch) references branch(branch_id) on delete cascade;
ERROR 1061 (42000): Duplicate key name 'fk_student'
```

The MUL key is still there after deleting the foreign key.
Now when i try to add another foreign key with same name, i this get error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue caused by implicit index creation. When you create foreign key `fk_student` index `fk_student` created too. If you need to rollback FK creattion you need next:

```
alter table student drop foreign key fk_student, drop key fk_student;
```

Look [SQL fiddle here](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=&sqlses=4a85154c3e01991690041d1dd63b6b7f&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)